# Custom Function in Sheets needs permission to access Google Groups

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets, custom-function

Trying to create a custom function attached to a Google Sheet that will query the emails inside a Google Group that I am the administrator for. I am using this method:

```
GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("ListName@DomainName").hasUser("MemberEmail")
```

which should return a `Boolean` result.

When I hard code the `ListName@DomainName` and `MemberEmail` values and log results, the function works fine. But when I call the function from the attached Sheet (passing arguments in place of the hard-coded values), I get Error:

```
You do not have permission to call getGroupByEmail (line 12).
```

I've tested multiple simplifications and always get the same error, even though a simple custom function in the same Sheet works just fine passing arguments and returning results. I am the admin on the entire domain and owner of the Group, so actual lack of permission should not be the problem. Can someone help me identify the steps I need to take to authorize the function in Sheets to access Groups info? Thanks, Clem